In the case of the last status, assign 'yes' in iracle sql
I have table in oracle sql.
CREATE TABLE person_status (
  user_id number,
  status_1 varchar(50),
   status_1_date date,
  status_2 varchar(50),
   status_2_date date,
  status_3 varchar(50),
   status_3_date date,
status_4 varchar(50),
   status_4_date date,
status_5 varchar(50),
   status_5_date date)
) 
INSERT INTO person_status VALUES (1,'Active','5/7/2024 12:15:20 PM','Suspend,'5/6/2024 05:20:09 PM','Active','11/28/2023 01:47:02 PM','Suspend','5/5/2024 12:10:08 PM','Suspend','3/27/2024 01:28:10 PM');
INSERT INTO person_status VALUES (2,'Active','5/7/2024 12:15:20 PM','Active,'5/6/2024 05:20:09 PM','Active','11/28/2023 01:47:02 PM','Active','5/5/2024 12:10:08 PM','Active','3/27/2024 01:28:10 PM');
INSERT INTO person_status VALUES (3,'Suspend','5/7/2024 12:15:20 PM','Suspend,'5/6/2024 05:20:09 PM','Suspend','11/28/2023 01:47:02 PM','Suspend','5/5/2024 12:10:08 PM','Suspend','3/27/2024 01:28:10 PM');


I want select data under these conditions:

If the subscriber has all the offers in the suspend status, then
assign Yes to the offer that was given this status most recently.
If    the subscriber has all the offers in the Active status, then
assign    Yes to the offer that was given this status most recently.
If the    subscriber has some offers in the active status and some
in the    suspend status, then assign Yes to the offer which was
given the    active status  most recently.

I compared statuses and dates, but a long list came up to cover all possible cases
output for user 1:



user_id
status_1
type_1
status_2
type_2
status_3
type_3
status_4
type_4
status_5
type_5




1
Active
Yes
Suspend
No
Active
No
Suspend
No
Suspend
No




Can you show your best attempt at solving these?

What is the output you are expecting ?

As a general design point, having repeating columns is normally a sign of bad design and generally makes querying the data harder

What happens when all offers were assigned the same status  on the same date and that date is the most recent?
